# Is Chinese great firewall white or black list based?

Tags: network, firewalls, webserver

Is a new website blocked by default in China ?

I just put online a new website dedicated to chinese people (a [working days calculator in China](http://china.workingdays.org), nothing subversive indeed). 
However a friend of a friend living in Beijing told me that my web site is not reachable from there !

Is by default a new website not authorized in China ? 
Is the blocking system white list or black list based ?

I am aware that it exists online checkers but these tools use ping commands and my website hoster does not respond to ping anyway so these tool are not helping me.

My website is on a mutual hosting, could that be a possible reason for my site being blocked ? do I need a dedicated server ?

What could I do to make it authorized ? 
How could I request to the chinese authorities a reconsideration of the website ?

Comment: i think this question might be better off on webmasters.SE

Comment: Voted to close.  Anyone here who can do more than speculate on the details of The Great Firewall's configuration is probably not at liberty to disclose them.

Comment: While there are bits of this question which could make for good questions themselves, speculation on the specific rules the Great Firewall implements is off topic and could change at any time.

Comment: I like how they blacklist a ton of crap yet they can still hack and crack so effectively..

Answer (score 7):

The details are technically a secret, but there are a few things we know:

- There are IP-based blacklist restrictions for popular sites like Facebook, and probably many other sites we don't hear about.
- There are content filter-based restrictions placed globally. That is, if you mention a blacklisted word or phrase, you connection will be dropped, and reconnect attempts will fail for a short time (a second or two).

---

One thing worth noting about your site in particular is that approximately 400 other websites are using that same IP address.

http://whois.domaintools.com/94.23.151.19

If you're worried about being on a blacklist, I suggest getting a unique IP for the domain, so that you only have to worry about *yourself* being on the blacklist, rather than all of your neighbors as well.

Comment: Having a unique IPv4 is sort of tough.  I mean does a yacp ( yet another calender application ) website require a unique static ip address?  Even if they do get a unique ip address there is no guarantee the ip address wasn't block in the past.